# Is there a way to turn binary into a QR code programmatically?

Tags: python, colors, binary, converters

I have the following:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1   1   1 1   1     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1           1     1 1 1 1 1     1   1           1
1   1 1 1   1   1 1 1         1     1   1 1 1   1 
1   1 1 1   1   1 1 1   1   1 1     1   1 1 1   1 
1   1 1 1   1   1     1 1   1 1 1   1   1 1 1   1 
1           1       1 1   1     1   1           1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                    1   1     1 1                 
1 1 1 1     1   1   1 1 1 1   1 1 1     1 1 1   1 
    1         1     1   1 1 1   1     1   1       
1 1   1 1 1 1     1 1 1 1 1     1         1       
    1 1 1     1   1 1           1 1       1 1 1   
    1 1 1 1 1 1   1 1   1   1     1 1 1 1   1 1   
      1   1   1 1 1   1 1   1 1 1   1 1 1   1 1 1 
  1   1     1 1 1     1   1           1       1   
1   1 1 1 1     1   1 1     1         1       1 1 
    1   1 1 1 1 1   1   1   1   1 1 1 1 1   1 1   
                1   1       1 1 1       1 1 1   1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1     1 1     1 1   1   1   1     1 1 
1           1     1   1   1 1 1 1       1         
1   1 1 1   1     1       1 1   1 1 1 1 1         
1   1 1 1   1   1 1 1             1 1   1 1   1 1 
1   1 1 1   1   1 1         1   1   1 1 1     1   
1           1   1     1 1 1 1     1       1 1     
1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1   1 1             1     1 1 1 1
```

and it won't scan on a QR code reader. Is there any way I can change this into an actual QR code so that it is scannable?

Comment: what this ? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQRCode

Comment: In what format? Also, it might work better if you used some other symbol then "1", like "#" or something more "filling".

Comment: @CrazyCasta in a format readable by a scanner haha. So I guess an image

Comment: @CrazyCasta right... i think too .. he need create an image or change 1 with black square

Comment: @CrazyCasta is there a way to replace a character with a pixel of color?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a terminal, no, best you could do would be filling the entire square. Assuming you can save to an image and then open it, I'd suggest using pillow (as in my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it appears you already know which squares to make black and which not, you could just use [pillow](https://python-pillow.github.io/) to generate an image. You'll need to use [ImageDraw](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw) and [Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new). What you need to do is something like:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new('1', (width, height), color=1) # Background white
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.point((x, y), 0) # Draw black
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up turning the background of my text editor white, replacing all the `1` characters with two `█` characters `██`, taking a screenshot of it, and then scaling down the image so that it wasn't so spread out.

Just thought I'd add that in for completeness.